# Which context should be used Application or Activity for a Intent in startService()?

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-lifecycle, android-context

I'm wondering what the implications of using either activity or application context are for Intent().
When using the activity context is the service duration bound to the activity lifecycle?

```
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've given, the `Context` used in the call to

```
new Intent(Context, Class)
```

is 100% irrelevant.

The `Context` parameter in this `Intent` constructor is used for one purpose and one purpose ONLY, and that is to get the package name of your app. That's it. So you can use any `Context` you want from your app. This has absolutely no influence at all on the lifecycle or lifetime of anything, not does it bind anything to the `Context`.

---

As an alternative, you can also create the `Intent` this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("my.package.name", "my.class.name");
```

The results of this are identical to the example you gave.